# Remove scrollspy effect at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I'm using scrollspy bootstrap effect. Here is an example http://jsbin.com/huhavejipepi/1/edit?html,css,js

When the user is navigating the site at the top of the page, the scrollspy effect should be disabled . However as you can see from that example, even when the home section isn't showed the link at the top of the bar seems active. Maybe is it a bug? Any workaround is available?

Comment: This is the normal way that scrollspy works: it spies the content for all ids that match the .nav with the same ids and it will add class active if you are in that section of the page. If you have ids that are inside your content that are not inside your navigation, it will behave strangely. Where is "#Intro" you have that in your content but not in the navbar, so it's going to look for the nearest

Comment: Ok I got it scrollspy work but it seems so weird to show active status when actually that content isn't showed.

Comment: Ok maybe I have found a workaround to avoid this strange behave. I'm gonna try it and if it works, I'll post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two or three tricks you can do to avoid the non desired behavior. One of them could be for e.g:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#Intro" style="display:none;">Intro</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, you can add a hidden link to the first paragraph. Check here [demo](http://jsbin.com/tevuje/1/edit?html,css,js,output) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!